# Why does iOS 7 not work with Baikal server?

Tags: iphone, .htaccess, ios7, caldav, carddav

Since upgrading to iOS 7, my iPhone could no longer access my [Baikal](http://baikal-server.com) Card DAV server. On the project's GitHub page, there are several issues open regarding this issue, but none could help me getting my iPhone talk to the server. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is to add these lines to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
# iOS 7 (and later)
RewriteRule /.well-known/carddav /card.php [R,L]
RewriteRule /.well-known/caldav /cal.php [R,L]
# Mac OS X 10.10
Redirect /.well-known/carddav /card.php
```

You then setup the Cal DAV as described in the installation instructions. For Card DAV make sure to follow these steps.

1. Server `your.server.url` (without http[s]-prefixes)
2. User name and password
3. Make sure the Account URL in the advanced settings looks like this: `https://your.server.url/card.php/principals/username`

Comment: thank you. so much. this should be everywhere over the internet. I searched all google for several days, this is the only thing that worked for me (iOS 13, Baikal, uberspace with several domains) - though I added the entire path to cal.php (in my case, baikal/html/cal.php) in case that makes any difference to anyone. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I used the Flat File method via FTP and no .well-known directory is made. Therefore, I removed .well-known and made it work with:

```
RewriteRule /carddav /card.php [R,L]
RewriteRule /caldav /cal.php [R,L]
```

This is also above the rule:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

I am running my web server via a different port as well. Thanks for your config, just a little tweaking was required to make life good.

```
iPhone 5S IOS 7.0.4
Baikal FLAT FILE 0.2.7
Synology NAS 412+ DSM 4.3-3827
```